# For a whistling language, what other keys could be used to represent tones/tone actions

Tags: conlang-creation, phonology, music

I already have used ~,<,>,’,=,-,^, and v for trills, rising tones, falling tones, glottal stops, chord tones, neutral tones, rising/falling tone, and falling/rising tone. This language is structured like music. Letters in exponents denote the lowest part on a chord, or the final tone in any other sequence. All moving tones are 3 tones except trills, which are 4 tones. Are there any other keys on a standard english keyboard that could be used and make sense for whistling? Please include how to get the character if option is used.

Comment: I don't know which character, but in case you need to map something unusual: Autohotkey is invaluable to me for mapping unusual characters. You write the keymapping script which shall run in the background in a text editor (I use Notepad++) after a straightforward fashion you can see on its website. e.g., ">!a::Send á" tells it when you press Right (>) Alt (!) and a, type an accented a.

Comment: Thanks for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of your main goals is to be easy to type, I'd recommend **repurposing Latin letters**. This is quite common in real-world languages, since a lot of international standards are now based on the English alphabet.

The Romanized Popular Alphabet, for example, repurposes miscellaneous letters for the tones of Hmong (aka Hmoob). *B* indicates a high tone, *s* a low tone, *j* a falling tone, *v* a rising tone, *m* or *d* a creaky tone, and *g* a breathy tone. There's no inherent connection between these letters and the tones they represent, but they're easy to type and won't cause issues on passports and official documents.

If you don't want to use letters, it would help if you explained your goals in more detail (like what other things you're trying to represent).

Comment: That’s a brilliant idea. Hadn’t thought of that.